# Play Games Services - How to show "progress saved by play games"

Tags: google-play-games

I have implemented google play games, sign in and cloud save, successfully.
My specific doubt is that i've seen in other games that after login, play games shows first the "welcome" message. And just after that, another message that says "progress saved by play games".
I can't manage to make that last message appear. The welcome message DOES appear, but the progress one it does not.

Did anybody make something specific to make it show? Is it automatic?
Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It is automatically shown, after the game service is published and has accumulated a certain number of players (somewhere around 500 or 1000).

Reference: my own experience